# How to save the token to use for other APIs using MaxSoft IntelliAPI Framework?

Tags: rest, api, automation

I need to save the access token by providing the username and password for the login request. Then that token should be able to use to authorize other API requests. I am using MaxSoft IntelliAPI Framework for API Test Automation.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the below steps to save the access token.

1. Open “api_doc.xlsx” file inside resources/api_document
2. Provide relevant details for “API_NAME”, “API_ENDPOINT”, “HTTP_METHOD” and “JSON_PAYLOAD_TEMPLATE” columns with respect to your login API request enter image description here
3. Save the excel file
4. Create a new specification in specs folder using any name
5. You can give any name for Specification heading and Scenario heading
6. In the first step, you must define the API name which you need to invoke. That API name should be included in the “api_doc.xlsx” file
7. For this example I am going to use “Login” as the API name since I have provided those details in the excel file in step 2
8. Now you can write the first step as,

   ```
   * Given that a user needs to invoke "Login"
   ```
9. As the second step, you need to configure the authentication token. Since the login request doesn’t contain the token, we can provide configuration values as N/A

   ```
   * And the user set the request authentication configurations as follows
       |Configuration                                                     |Configuration Value|
       |------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------|
       |Is authentication required?                                       |Yes                |
       |Do you need to retrieve the access token from the text file?      |Yes                |
       |Provide the access token if you need to authorize the API manually|N/A                |
   ```
10. In the third step, you must create the JSON payload by replacing the values which was provided in the “api_doc.xlsx” file. Since my login payload contains the “username” and “password” properties and I have defined their values as “#username” and “#password” in the excel file, I will write the step as follows,

    ```
    * And the user set the request attributes as follows  
        |Attribute Value In JSON Template|Attribute Value To Be Set|  
        |--------------------------------|-------------------------|  
        |#username                       |osanda                   |  
        |#password                       |Password1                |
    ```
11. As the fourth step, I can invoke the API as follows,

    ```
    * When the user invokes the API
    ```
12. ow I have invoked the API and I have the response as well. So I can validate the response using the following steps.
13. So in the fifth step, we’ll validate the status code of the response,

    ```
    * Then the status code for the request is "201"
    ```
14. Then we’ll validate the response contents using JSON Path Assertions as follows,

    ```
    * And the JSON Path Assertions for the response should be equal to the following  
        |JSON Path     |Expected Result|  
        |--------------|---------------|  
        |$.status      |success        |
    ```
15. Usually in the login response we can find the access token which will be used to authorize the next requests. So all we need to do is, save that token. It can be done as follows,

    ```
    * And save the access token which is the attribute value of "data" in the response
    ```
16. Now you have already completed the designing phase. You can execute this test scenario by clicking the green color play button on the left corner of the scenario heading
17. After you run the test, go to resources/access_tokens and open “access_token_to_be_used_for_testing.txt”
18. You can see the saved token.
19. Now that saved token will be automatically retrieved from the other API requests when you use the request authentication configuration step as below.

    ```
    * And the user set the request authentication configurations as follows

        |Configuration                                                     |Configuration Value|  
        |------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------|  
        |Is authentication required?                                       |Yes                |  
        |Do you need to retrieve the access token from the text file?      |Yes                |  
        |Provide the access token if you need to authorize the API manually|N/A                |
    ```